# Error accessing github account locally

Tags: git, github, config

I have added ssh key for my local repo(which I cloned from my github repo.

When I try to push the commit to the remote github repo, I get the following message:

```
fatal: 'git@github.com/username/reponame.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I also tried changing remote name to `git://github.com/username/reponame.git`, but it didn't work.

Where can I specify my username/password to access the remote repo (or if it's embedded in the unique ssh key and it's just that I am doing something wrong, then help) ?

Note - I have my ssh key entered in my github account.

Please guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a typo in the URL for the github repo:

```
git@github.com/username/reponame.git
```

Instead you should be using:

```
git@github.com:username/reponame.git
```

To update the URL for the remote named origin:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/reponame.git
```

Try a `git fetch origin` after that to see if you're able to fetch the changes from the remote. If that works, you should be able to run `git push origin` as well (provided your SSH keys are valid and you've followed the steps to add them to your github account correctly).